# how can i get the control from the ui elements from another app?

Tags: android

Somebody knows how can i get the control from the ui elements from another app?.

For example, in whatsapp how could I write in the EditText to send a message using speech to text?

Thanks in advance!!

Greetings.

Comment: From another app wowo

Comment: Or anything that is being displayed on the screen. I'm lost :S

Comment: You don't, it would create a ton of issues least of which might be security.

Comment: well try making an app that has a `background service` and a custom keyboard. then handle that app from other phone using some online service like api... It might work, but it will require a lot of work and time...

Answer (score 0):

You interact with other apps stored on the device using the [Intent framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). What you are asking is literally impossible, unless you're talking about hacking the device.

Answer (score 0):

In Android all apps are separated from each other. If your app wants to access data from another app to show it in your custom ui, the vendor of the application must provide a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html).

If the publisher of the target app has declared some activities with intent-filters, the ui components can be opened by wrapping your data inside of an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html).
In such cases the availability of at least one matching intent filter should be checked, before sending the Intent.